# LINQ to SQL as Unit of Work

Tags: linq-to-sql, unit-of-work

From your experience, is LINQ to SQL appropriate as a Unit of Work? is it avoidable? should I prefer, say, NHibernate or another O/RM tool?

Thanks,
Lucian

Comment: I'm not sure your question is as clear as it could be. What do you mean by  "Unit of Work"? Could you describe what you are seeking to accomplish with these tools? For example, are you creating a website or desktop app whose data is saved in a database? Are you looking for the best data-access tool?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Linq to Sql data context is designed to be used for a single unit of work.

Edit: to add references.

[The Linq To SQL FAQ:](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/3ae5e457-099e-4d13-9a8b-df3ed4ba0bab/)

> Q: Should I create a new DataContext in every business logic method?
>
> A: The DataContext conforms to the Unit of Work design pattern.  Unless you are moving data between physical tiers between each operation you should keep your DataContext alive for the duration of work.

Comment: Some links, if possible, please?